# in p4perl what is the time format that is returned?

Tags: perl, perforce

I have started using [p4perl](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/p4script/perl.p4.html). When I run p4 change using the api it returns me a strange number in place of time.

I am getting `time:1494525845` and when i see the `p4 describe` of the same i see that the time is `2017/05/11 14:04:05`

Does anyone know how to map the large number to a human readable format?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) in conjunction with [POSIX](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POSIX)'s `strftime` to convert the [epoch timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) to something localized and human-readable.